# preprocess ID images before extract the text?

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract, text-extraction, data-preprocessing, image-preprocessing

[image: ID image]

I need to extract text from these type of Sri Lankan ID images. But before that I need to preprocess the input image. I am going to use Tesseract OCR to extract text from the images. Can anyone suggest me some flow of methods to preprocess the ID image to get better results?

I tried to remove background pattern from the image before extract the text. But I couldn't remove it properly.